# Poor mobile performance when running from Eclipse

Tags: java, android, performance, mobile, eclipse

So after weeks of thinking my rendering code was bad, I accidentally discovered the following:

**Running my game on a Nexus S**

- From Eclipse (Debug as -> Android application): 12fps
- From the device
  while still attached to USB (getting log info in Eclipse still):
  24fps
- From the device while not attached via USB: 56fps

I was wondering if anyone else has issues like this?  I mean, the problem really isn't a problem since the final release build will likely have good performance, but for the time being I don't want to have to keep (un)plugging my device in and out when testing code all day long.

Is there some remedy for this or does anyone have any input/advice?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't use Eclipse, but I do not have these issues while running from Android Studio; except of course when the Debugger is attached, but that is to be expected. Have you considered using an emulator (such as [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/)) instead of your device for your daily runtime environment? I use this setup (it runs as fast/faster than my Nexus 4) and then only do device testing when needed (i.e. at various milestones). Of course this won't work if you need multi-touch or gyro support.

Comment: I think this should be on StackOverflow rather than here since it really has nothing to do with gamedev.

Comment: @you I think it's OK here: A good guideline for whether to post here over StackOverflow is "Would a *game developer* give a better answer than another developer?" Using Eclipse to develop and test Android apps *is common*, but rendering performance is considerably more important in games than general app development.

Answer (score 1):

The debugger has to attach to the process, and it is what is causing your device to run more slowly than normal

It doesn't matter if you "debug" the app or not -- if it is set in the device, eclipse will debug

Answer (score 0):

Debugging the app is expected to slow the device down.

The reason why you are slowing down even while not debugging is probably related to excessive logging.

Comment: I'm actually not logging anything though.  I know debugging an app can make it slower, but I didn't expect if I just ran the app while connected via USB would have (nearly) the same slowdown.

So I guess there's no solution other than to unplug my device when I need to test stuff on it?

Comment: Well, wait and see if there are any other solutions. I'm surprised that this is happening, maybe some apps on your device are programmed to do something when they see that the device is being charged?